# Secure handling of string variables

Tags: c, string, security, variables, printf

Hello I'm quite new to C and in a nutshell I was doing the following as part of my assignment in class:

```
foo (char *var) {
  printf(var);
}
```

I was told that this is bad practice and insecure but did not get much detailed information on this by my tutor. I assume that if the string value of var is controllable by the user it may be used to perform a bufferoverflow? How would I properly harden this code? Do I have to limit the str length or something?

Cheers & Thanks!

Comment: yes, limit the string length to avoid probable invalid memory access. Also a NULL pointer check...

Comment: The first parameter to `printf` is the format string. Having the caller specify it is a recipe for disaster. Consider what would happen if the user passed in `"%s"`

Comment: Take a look at http://www.dwheeler.com/secure-programs (A detailed HOWTO on secure programming)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use:

```
printf("%s", var);
```

instead.  The way you have it, I could enter `%s` as my input, and `printf` would read a random piece of memory as it looked for a string to print.  That can cause any amount of unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Better yet `puts` (or `fputs` if you want to avoid the extra newline)

Comment: And then it could either result in a crash or information disclosure or damage data, all sorts of things.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker `puts()` appends `\n`, in case it matters.

Answer (score 6):

This is **UNSAFE** because it could lead to a [Format String Attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncontrolled_format_string)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first argument of [printf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) is a format string.  So the caller of your function could pass:

```
foo("%d")
```

and then `printf` would look for an integer which isn't there, and cause undefined behaviour.  One possible fix would be for your function to call:

```
printf("%s", var);
```

which would have `printf` interpret `var` as a regular string (rather than a format).

Answer (score 0):

Printf has the following signature:

```
int printf(
   const char *format [,
   argument]... 
);
```

If the user inputs format characters for example %s all kinds of bad things will happen.

Use puts if you just want to output the string.