# How to printf() a user class?

Tags: c++

The program fails while compiling the code. Compiler points to `printf("Version = '%s'\n", gABXVER)`. I guess that I actually can't write `gABXVER = "V1R1"`, but I don't have any other idea.

```
class CISPFVar_BINSTR : public CISPFVar
{
protected:
    char* m_pBuffer;
    long  m_bDefined;
public:
   ...
    void Initialize(char* szName, long lSize, int bDefineVar = 1)
    {
        Uninitialize();
        ZStrToCharArray(szName, m_cName, 8);
        m_Size = lSize+1;
        m_pBuffer = (char*)malloc(m_Size);
        m_pBuffer[0] = 0;
        if (bDefineVar)
           ISPLINK(__VDEFINE, m_cName, m_pBuffer, __BINSTR, &m_Size);
        m_bDefined = bDefineVar;
    }
      ...    
};

CISPFVar_BINSTR gABXVER;
char szLoadLibraryPath[50];

int main(
    int argc,
    char* argv[])
{
    if (argc > 1)
      if (argv[1]) strcpy(szLoadLibraryPath, argv[1]);

      gABXVER.Initialize("ABXVER",4);

    gABXVER = "V1R1";

    printf("Version = '%s'\n", gABXVER);

    return 0;
};
```

Comment: Whether you can assign a C string literal to your class depends on code in `CISPFVar_BINSTR` or `CISPFVar` you haven't shown. (The exact error message should help. Care to share it?) In any case, `printf` is a C function. It can be called from C++, but it can only handle basic data types. Therefore you must convert your class to a null-terminated `char *` somehow before you can print it. It might be better to write a `<<` operator for your class and a C++ output stream.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? What you desire `printf()` to output?

Comment: Are you reading the answers here? Would you mind to copy/paste the compiler errors intop this post?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `%s` in `printf` family of functions, the corresponding argument type needs to be `const char*` or something that can be converted to `const char*`. The argument you are using is not such a type. Perhaps you meant to use:

```
printf("Version = '%s'\n", gABXVER.m_pBuffer);
```

Comment: It needs to be a pointer to `char` or an array of `char`, possibly cv-qualified. "The lvalue-to-rvalue (4.1), array-to-pointer (4.2), and function-to-pointer (4.3) standard conversions are performed on the argument expression" (5.2.2/7)

Comment: It "needs to be" semantically; the language itself couldn't care less. Newer compilers tend to inspect the format string (provided it's a literal) and issue a warning if the params don't match, but it's more of an attempt to help the programmer avoid C's unsafe shores. I'm saying this not to nitpick, but because passing the wrong type as such can't be the source of a compiler error (unless "warnings as errors" is specified as a compilation option).

Comment: If you want to produce a program that runs correctly, then it needs to be. If for whatever reason you are only interested in something that compiles, you may or may not get away with something else, depending on your compiler.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler should compile just fine (with possible warnings for printf) because printf doesn't care what you pass to it (beyond the first parameter) or whether it matches the format string. Modern compilers or error checking progs like lint will issue a warning if the params obviously don't match, and if you have a setting "treat warnings as errors", the prog may fail to compile.

That said, CISPFVar_BINSTR needs a public copy constructor if you want to pass it as a parameter by value to a function (because at least semantically a copy will be made). Does it have one? As others remarked it's customary to help your helpers by providing any information you have. Here we are badly missing the compiler errors. (You can edit your post at any time.)

I could imagine that the class has a conversion to char* or std::string, so it may suffice to try either `printf("Version = '%s'\n", (char *)gABXVER)` or `printf("Version = '%s'\n", (std::string(gABXVER)).c_str() )`.

Comment: "Passing a potentially-evaluated argument of class type (Clause 9) having a non-trivial copy constructor, a non-trivial move constructor, or a non-trivial destructor, with no corresponding parameter, is conditionally-supported with implementation-defined semantics" (5.2.2/7)

Comment: Correct citation. Afaict This supports what I said (copy ctor needed). One can possibly read it such that you can get away with just a move ctor (if the argument is an rvalue, e.g. a temporary).

Comment: @n.m. Or were you referring to the "conditionally-supported"? True, even with a ctor an implementation can refuse to compile. Worth noting -- the ctors are a necessary but not necessarily sufficient requirement ;-).

Answer (score 0):

You can only `printf` things that have format specifiers designed specifically for them. There is no format specifier that accepts a value of class type, so you cannot `printf` one directly.

The best thing you can do is explicitly convert your object to a `const char*` and pass the result to `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

In c++ you can use many techniques to implement things like [streaming operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z2f6c2k.aspx)

```
#include <iostream>

class Whatever
{
    int value = 42;

public:
    int Get() const {
        return value;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Whatever const&);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Whatever const& what) {
    os << what.Get();
    return os;
}

int main() {
    Whatever x;
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

printf [is unsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14436941/847349)

In effect, you're doing [serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) of your object into a readable string.